# How to check if mouse is inside an "invisible" box on screen without css(JavaScript and jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

Is there a way to check if a mouse is within a certain box on the screen. I don't know to export the jQuery variable as an integer to use in a Javascript `if statement`. I know this is possible with `div`, but I don't want to use `div` because I will need a lot of these `if statements`, I don't want to clutter my CSS. I am open to ideas that are more efficient than what I have without using CSS.

So far this is all I have...

```
$(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;
});  

if(mouseX > 80 && mouseX < 200 && mouseY > 80 && mouseY < 200){
    alert("Message");
}
```

Comment: `$(document).mouseenter(function(ev){ var current = ev.target; })`

Comment: share your html code and explain what you ment by "box"... need more explanation from you end mate.

Comment: JQuery and JavaScript is kind of the same but JQuery is easier (my opinion) and what you mean by _don't want to clutter my CSS_ CSS doesn't get cluttered if you know how use it. Also there's far less information to answer this. And you're saying No CSS, No JQuery and No JavaScript so what you want the solution to be in Python ?

Comment: Do you want to convert this jQuery call to a vanilla? `document.addEventListener('mousemove' , exactlySameFunction)` but you should include the if statement inside the event handler since here you'll only get *mouseX is undefined* in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have access to `mouseX` and `mouseY` inside the `if-statement` you need to declare them outside of the `mousover`-function-handler to make them global.
You can read more about [scope by todd motto](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

## Solutions for your problem

```
var mouseX
var mouseY
$(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
    // override mouseX and mouseY
    mouseX = event.pageX
    mouseY = event.pageY
});

// access to mouseX and mouseY
if (mouseX > 80 && mouseX < 200 && mouseY > 80 && mouseY < 200) {
    alert("Message")
}
```

You could write the if-statement inside the handler to [avoid global scope](https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478)

```
$(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
    var mouseX = event.pageX
    var mouseY = event.pageY

    if (mouseX > 80 && mouseX < 200 && mouseY > 80 && mouseY < 200) {
        alert("Message")
    }
});
```

## But don't use mousemove on document

`$(document).on('mousemove', function(){/*...*/})` will be execute *everytime* you move the mouse on the page - this isn't realy what you want.
Instead you could use `mouseenter` on the element you want to observe.

```js
function observeHover(event) {
  console.log(event.target)
}

$('.circle').on('mouseenter', observeHover)
```

```css
.box {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: IndianRed;
}

.circle {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: Indigo;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="box"></div>
<div id="two" class="box"></div>
<div id="three" class="circle"></div>
```